How to handle Node_Modules in a vss extension (for DevOps)
I'm building out a vss-extension that can be installed and used in a build pipeline.  I followed this sample from Microsoft.  My extension task is a nodejs script.
I've got the following folder structure for my extension:

[node_modules] (not bundled)
[scanTask]

icon.png
run_sensor.js
task.json


my-hub.html
package.json
vss-extension.json

Running npm install and executing run_sensor.js locally through visual studio code works perfectly.
I have an automated pipeline that, when the extension is checked in, it bundles the vsix and publishes to my "publisher" using these commands:
npm install -g tfx-cli
npx tfx-cli extension create  --manifest-globs vss-extension.json --root $(Build.SourcesDirectory) --output-path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
npx tfx extension publish --vsix $vsixFilePath --token $patToken --publisher $organizationOrPublisher --rev-version

So far so good! Publishes as expected.  I've installed this (private) extension into my organisation and run it in my pipeline with:
- task: scanTask@3
  inputs:
    repoDirectory: '$(buildDirectory)'

This runs fine but fails because my run_sensor.js requires "unzipper".  Sample:
console.log(`Running script...`);

const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
const unzipper = require('unzipper'); /*ERROR*/

// Get the current working directory
const currentDirectory = process.cwd();

// Print the command-line arguments and current directory
console.log(`Node Path: ${process.argv[0]}`);
console.log(`Script Path: ${process.argv[1]}`);
console.log(`Argument 3: ${process.argv[2]}`);
console.log(`The current working directory is: ${currentDirectory}`);
...

This line is causing the problem:
const unzipper = require('unzipper'); and gives this error:
2024-04-13T10:17:34.2926703Z ##[section]Starting: scanTask
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3048885Z ==============================================================================
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049056Z Task         : Scan sample
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049172Z Description  : Example task
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049294Z Version      : 3.14.0
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049371Z Author       : Me!
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049480Z Help         : Example help
2024-04-13T10:17:34.3049585Z ==============================================================================
2024-04-13T10:17:35.0945760Z Running script...
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2196175Z module.js:478
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2199321Z     throw err;
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2199629Z     ^
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2199753Z 
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2200496Z Error: Cannot find module 'unzipper'
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2200888Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2201241Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2201551Z     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2201862Z     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2202567Z     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\myaccount\agent1\_work\_tasks\scanTask_a12345\3.13.0\run_sensor.js:39:18)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2203032Z     at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2203365Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2203691Z     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2203984Z     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2213242Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2722743Z ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'C:\Users\myaccount\agent1\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"C:\Users\myaccount\agent1\_work\_tasks\scanTask_a12345\3.13.0\run_sensor.js"'.
2024-04-13T10:17:37.2742884Z ##[section]Finishing: scanTask

It's happening because the node_modules folder is not being deployed on the build agent running the task.  Sample output of the installed task:

I tried to update the package.json file by adding a "prestart" step to run npm install, as follows:
{
  "name": "my-ado-extension",
  "version": "3.14.0",
  "description": "Example task",
  "main": "run_sensor.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "node run_sensor.js"
  },
  "repository": {
  ...

It didn't fix the issue.
I've also tried adding unzipper to the dependencies of package.json but that also did not work:
...
"dependencies": {
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "^4.0.2",
    "unzipper": "^0.10.14"
  }

That hasn't worked either.
How do I deploy the unzipper node_module with the extension successfully?
Task.json is:
{ 
  "id": "a4234567-b49c-22d3-f456-526614176030",
  "name": "scanTask",
  "friendlyName": "Scan code",
  "description": "my description",
  "author": "Me!",
  "helpMarkDown": "Help mark down",
  "category": "DevOps",
  "visibility": [
    "Build",
    "Release"
  ],
  "demands": [],
  "version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Patch": 0
  },
  "instanceNameFormat": "Sample Task $(message)",
  "inputs": [
  ],
  "execution": {
    "Node": {
      "target": "run_sensor.js",
      "argumentFormat": "$(buildDirectory)"
    }
  }
}


May i know after you add prestart and dependency in packge.json, will the node_modules be correctly deployed under the task folder?  And What if you explicitly install the required module npm install unzipper before your custom task, will it work?

Unfortunately, that didn't seem to work - the node_modules didn't appear in the deployed task on the build agent and it didn't appear in the Build.SourcesDirectory.

Can you post the task.json?

I was able to work around the issue by adding the "node_modules" into the task folder and checking them into the vss-extension repo.  Not ideal.

Based on your description, you need to include the node_modules folder when creating the Azure DevOps Extension task.
The extension package will create based on the file vss-extension.json.
We can set the field files in the vss-extension.json to contain the node_modules folder. Refer to this doc:  Extension files
You can refer to the following methods:
Method1: Add the node_modules folder in the vss-extension.json -> files field .
For example:
....
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "scanTask",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules",
            "packagePath": "node_modules",
            "addressable": true
        }
    ],
....

Method2:You can manually/use command copy the node_modules to scanTask folder. Then you can directly create the extension package.
For example:
[node_modules] 
[scanTask]
  --node_modules
  --icon.png
  --run_sensor.js
  --task.json
my-hub.html
package.json
vss-extension.json

Result:

